# How to compile typescript for the browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an existing project that I would like to add TypeScript and React support to.  Because the project already exists, I can't use a scaffolding project and have been having trouble configuring `tsconfig.json` properly.

I have been having various issues depending on which settings I use, but generally I have errors from different code in `/node_modules/**` and often in `/node_modules/@types/**`.  I've included my `tsconfig.json` with comments as to what errors each setting fixes.

How can I compile my TypeScript + React project without import/module issues?

**Current relevant `tsconfig.json` settings**

```
"module": "amd", // must be 'amd' or 'system' to use 'outFile'
"lib": ["es2015", "dom", "es5", "es6"], // must include some of these to suppress certain errors; adds the 'Set' type
"jsx": "react", // compile jsx to js
"sourceMap": true, // ensure debuggable
"outFile": "./static/js/app.js", // must be under /static/ to be served
"rootDir": "./static/ts",
"moduleResolution": "node", // suppresses issue with `default` or `export`
"esModuleInterop": true
```

**Current Error**

`ReferenceError: define is not defined` (In the browser)

Comment: For some reason I can only find search results for running the typescript compiler itself in the browser.

Comment: That error indicates that you're trying to load AMD modules (`"module": "amd"`) without using an AMD-compatible module loader.  You likely shouldn't be using `"module": "amd"`.  What process did you use to combine your JavaScript files into one before you added TypeScript?  I can try to help you fit TypeScript into the existing process.

Comment: We weren't doing any transpiling prior.  I assumed single file would be the easiest solution to solving the import issue, but I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up using `webpack` (with the `ts-loader` module) instead of `tsc` as my static bundler.

The only change I had to make to my typescript was to change `import React from "react";` to `import * as React from "react"`.

**tsconfig.json** (abbr)

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
"allowJs": true,
"jsx": "react",
"sourceMap": true,
"rootDir": "./client",
"downlevelIteration": true,
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: './main.tsx',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'client.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/js')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js']
    },
};
```

Comment: webpack.config.js

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with a single file for now, then:

1. If you haven't done so already, follow [these instructions](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#step-2-add-the-script-tags) to add the React library to your page.  (You can download the JavaScript files and host them on your server if you prefer)
2. Delete the `import` statements from your file so that TypeScript doesn't treat it as a module, and just refer to the `React` and `ReactDOM` global variables that will be defined at runtime by the JavaScript files you added in step 1.  The `@types/react` package will automatically declare these ["UMD"](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) global variables at compile time when your code is not a module.